FastAPI & Pytest. Got Future attached to a different loop
The problem is this. I get an error when I try to make tests for my FastAPI application.
FAILED tests/test_users_api.py::test_create_jwt - RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-153' coro=<test_create_jwt() running at /backend/tests/test_users_api.py:22> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py:182]> got Future <Future pending cb=[BaseProtocol._on_waiter_completed()]> attached to a different loop
FAILED tests/test_users_api.py::test_create_user_with_valid_data - RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-179' coro=<test_create_user_with_valid_data() running at /backend/tests/test_users_api.py:122> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py:182]> got Future <Future pending cb=[BaseProtocol._on_waiter_completed()]> attached to a different loop


The error occurs when testing those functions where I work with the database via sqlalchemy.
Here is the code for my db sessions and dependency_override for FastAPI:
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="session")
async def engine(app_database_url, migrations) -> AsyncEngine:
    engine = create_async_engine(app_database_url)
    yield engine
    await engine.dispose()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def db_session(engine) -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with engine.connect() as connection:
        transaction = await connection.begin()
        session = AsyncSession(bind=connection, join_transaction_mode="create_savepoint", expire_on_commit=False)
        try:
            yield session
        except Exception:
            await session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            await session.close()
            await transaction.rollback()
            await connection.close()


@pytest.fixture
def session_override(db_session):

    async def get_session_override() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
        yield db_session

    main_app.dependency_overrides[db_helper.get_session] = get_session_override

My AsyncClient
@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def client(session_override) -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncClient, None]:
    async with AsyncClient(app=main_app, base_url="http://localhost:8000") as ac:
        yield ac

I tried making my fixture for event_loop
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()

But this did not change the situation
My pyproject.toml section with pytest settings
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = [
    "-vvv",
    "--cov=app",                   
    "--cov-report=term-missing", 
    "--cov-config=pyproject.toml"
]
python_files = "test_*.py"
filterwarnings = [
    "ignore::DeprecationWarning",
    "ignore::SyntaxWarning",
]
pythonpath = [
  ".", "backend",
]

asyncio_mode="auto"
asyncio_default_fixture_loop_scope = "session"


Project github https://github.com/DenisMaslennikov/to-do-list-FastAPI

I think you have to do something like this in your conftest.py (or somewhere) so first you create a new loop and then set it with asyncio.
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    yield loop
    loop.close()

and the way I have the session and engine is like below:
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_root_engine():
    engine = create_async_engine(ROOT_DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
    try:
        yield engine
    finally:
        await engine.dispose()

@asynccontextmanager
async def get_root_async_session():
    engine = create_async_engine(ROOT_DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
    async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)
    async with async_session() as session:
        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            await session.close()
    await engine.dispose()

and as well I do have
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
asyncio_mode=auto

and on each testing file on top I do have the below
import pytest

pytestmark = pytest.mark.asyncio

# Your tests go here

So basically you should reuse the engine and session from your code that way you do test it properly. (With some mocking for sure)
Hope this helps!

Thanks for the answer. I tried adding your fixture and unfortunately I still get the same error.

@DenisMaslennikov updated the comment take a look again if that helps

Thanks again. But unfortunately this won't help.

I have asyncio_mode=auto set
I have pytest.mark.asyncio on all tests.
I do not reuse the session from the app, but this is necessary to correctly rollback changes from tests and ensure test isolation (I don't think that's the problem).

